# What is the difference between REGEX engine of QUERY and REGEXEXTRACT formulas in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I've found there are 2 regex languages in Google Sheets.

First is used in formulas:

`REGEXEXTRACT`

`REGEXREPLACE`

`REGEXMATCH`

Second is used in `QUERY`

```
=QUERY({A4:C};"where Col1 matches 'West|East'")
```

The syntax for regular REGEX-like formulas is described here:

https://github.com/google/re2/blob/main/doc/syntax.txt

I've done quick research for [`QUERY`](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/querylanguage) regex and made this table:

[image]

You may see I've found some interesting differences about `QUERY` regex:

- always matches the whole string, and you need to add `.*` if needed.
- surprisingly supports "Lookahead" `(?=group)`
- cannot use flags `(?i)`, `(?m)`
- by default fetches single lines of text only, but supports newline `\n`

Do you have your own research, or found some official docs?

Comment: I'm sure you know this, so for other folks looking to use flags: https://i.stack.imgur.com/NeclT.png

Comment: Negative lookahead `(?!...)` also works. And the main point is that `MATCHES` in `QUERY()` only returns true if regex matches the whole string. `REGEXMATCH` returns true if any part of a string matches the pattern.

Comment: Named groups work in this syntax: `(?<name>...)`.

Answer (score -2):

### Sheets specific functions

As you stated, there are three different **Sheets functions** that make use of this "matching" functionality: `REGEXEXTRACT`, `REGEXREPLACE` and `REGEXMATCH`. They accomplish different goals yet their syntactical implementation is pretty similar. You can find their documentation here:

- `REGEXEXTRACT`. [Documentation](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098244).
- `REGEXREPLACE`. [Documentation](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098245).
- `REGEXMATCH`. [Documentation](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098292).

And, as you stated, the full documentation on the syntax they use can be found here: https://github.com/google/re2/blob/main/doc/syntax.txt

---

### Query function

The `QUERY` function (you can read its documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/querylanguage)) uses the well-known **SQL syntax**, (notwithstanding the few exceptions listed in the documentation where they differ). In the official documentation there is a summary about basic **SQL syntax** ([here](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/querylanguage)), but of course for more detail you would need to go to the **SQL documentation**.

Comment: This answer does not add any information